# Debugging on-launch Javascript in UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, javascript-debugger, safari-web-inspector

I'm currently debugging a webpage which is embedded in a UIWebView for display in the app.

It uses some elaborate on-load Javascript which works fine in the Android app but breaks in the iOS app.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12552686/225176) pointed me to Safari Web Inspector for UIWebView - however, since the broken Javascript is being run on page load, I can't actually attach the inspector in time to capture whatever's going wrong.

Right now I'm hacking around it by manually inserting a delay into the page, but is there a better way (one that doesn't require I make changes to the page code itself, start the app, rush to load it up in Safari, then wait a while longer for it to continue)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Important edit**: in Safari 7.0, you can reload the page by selecting the "Resources" view, and clicking the refresh arrow next to the top-level page.  [It seems you can also do it in at least some versions of Safari 6 by selecting the document tab, clicking the top-level page to select it, and pressing Command+R (the same shortcut used to refresh the page in normal Safari).]  Breakpoints you set will still exist if you refresh the page from the Safari Web Inspector, because doing so does not cause SWI to detach the way reloading the page from within your app or the Xcode debugger does.  This means that *as long as the page doesn't do a Javascript redirect or trigger side-effects in the app itself, you can step through the onload Javascript by loading the page once, setting your breakpoint there, and then reloading the page from within SWI*.

**Original post**: The only solution I was able to find was putting in an "extra" call to `shouldStartLoadWithRequest:` as follows:

1. Add a script (*not* onload, synchronous) as the first element in the page head:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       window.location = "myapp://catchme";
   </script>
   ```
2. Set an XCode breakpoint in `shouldStartLoadWithRequest:`
3. Edit the breakpoint to set a condition of:

   ```
   (bool)[[[request URL] absoluteString] isEqualToString:@"myapp://catchme"]
   ```

   (Without this condition it will stop on the initial `shouldStartLoadWithRequest:` call, which isn't what you want because the page won't yet be available to attach the Mobile Web Inspector to at this stage.)
4. Start the page load, and when it hits the (Xcode) breakpoint, switch to Safari, and launch Mobile Web Inspector with Develop > iPhone Simulator > (my page), then switch back to Xcode and resume execution within a short window before all the resource requests on the page time out.

Comment: Well, I go a problem, even though I return NO if request url is myapp://catchme, my orginal page is not loaded

Comment: for reference: if you are running up to date software, just hit cmd + r on the safari inspector to reload the webview

Answer (score 0):

[Weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre-docs/latest/) helped me to solve this issue, since it's connected right from the start, you get full control of the page.

Answer (score -1):

Why not putting a breakpoint in shouldStartLoadWithRequest and then open the inspector?

Comment: Unfortunately, when shouldStartLoadWithRequest: is called, the webview is not available to inspect in Safari > Develop > iPhone Simulator.  And by the time webViewDidFinishLoad: is called, the window.onload event has already been triggered.  Are there any other events you know of that might suffice for the breakpoint.

Answer (score -1):

Not 100% related to the question OP asked, but I had a similar problem with an *Android* WebView, in a mobile app whose native code I do not control (but which has WebView debugging enabled).

- `document.reload()` and all other similar means of reloading the page were not working for me
- I was thinking to put `alert()` at the very top of the page, which in theory is a blocking call, but it was not working for me either.
- Finally, I went with a blocking, synchronous XHR.

In order to inject an artificial delay when the page is loading, I added a fake call to an endpoint under my control that returns 200 OK after 15 seconds.

Put this at the very top of the `<head>`

```
  <script>
    try {
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open('GET', 'https://whatever/please-freeze', false); // false = sync XHR
      request.send(null);
    } catch (err){
      debugger;
    };
    debugger;
  </script>
```

You can for example create your own simple http server with an endpoint behaving like this, but this is a bit of an overkill.

The `debugger` statements didn't trigger breakpoints in Chrome for whatever reason, but the manually defined breakpoints in the dynamically loaded code (created before) worked fine.

## A hack for Windows (Fiddler) users

Since I'm on Windows, I used Fiddler to **create an autoresponder with latency.**

[image: fiddler autoresponder with latency]

I also used Fiddler to edit the HTML of the original page request, to inject the `<script>` mentioned earlier.