# Embedded timeline widget of Twitter not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, uiwebview

I created a twitter widget and plugged it into an app. I have integrated this html code in UIWebView i.e.

```
NSString *html="<html><body><a class=\"twitter-timeline\" href=\"https://twitter.com/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx" data-widget-id=\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\" height=\"532\"></a><script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+\"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js\";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,\"script\",\"twitter-wjs\");</script></body</html>"

[self.webview loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

It works fine on iOS > 6.0 but it does not work iOS < 6.0.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Siddharth Chopra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry haven't ios < 6.0 simulators for test it, but I think there is some problems with browser(safari) and you can debug javascript inside of a uiwebview. Here is [how to debug javascript inside a WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767902/what-are-some-methods-to-debug-javascript-inside-of-a-uiwebview)

Comment: hi UIugbek,                                                       Thanks for your answer but i dont not have a problem with browser. Actually, html code that loaded in UIWebView is not working in iPhone 4 with Version 5.1.1. but its working fine in version 6.1.3. Any idea regarding this?

Comment: Hi Siddh, In your task there is just one difference between ios, it is sfari engines, different ios version use dofferent safari engines. And your javascript have some problmes with safari engine that based on ios 5.1.1, the only way for undersending the problem it's debuging your javascript

Comment: Hi UIugbek, Thanks for your answer but now scrolling of Embedded timeline is not smooth in iPhone as compared to Android mobiles. Do you have any idea regarding this?

Comment: Yeah, scrolling on UIWebView slower then on UITableView, I think you can't fix it. But if You did find some solution please share with us. Thanks