# Enable web inspector on a webview in Swift

Tags: webview, swift, web-inspector

Trying to build an iPad app with a webview, how would you go about adding the web inspector using swift?

Answer (score 8):

if you are trying in WKWebView then you can bring *WebInspector* using the following code snippet

```
preferences.setValue(true, forKey:"developerExtrasEnabled")
```

Here is the [complete code](http://justpaste.it/qqn6) if anybody wants to try

As far as I have tried it works in OSX and not in iOS

[image]

I have raised a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34927983/730807) for this anomaly

### Update

*WKPreference* is *not key value coding-compliant* for the key *developerExtrasEnabled* so we can't do this using this approach.

Hence the easiest approach would be

Plug the phone into your mac and inspect it through the Safari Develop menu..Here are the steps to achieve it.

If you're using iOS >= 6 and you have mountain lion (10.8) or Safari >= 6, you can just:

- Open the application in the simulator (or your device in XCode >= 4.5.x)
- Open Safari (go to Preferences -> Advanced and make sure "Show Develop Menu in Menubar" is on.
- From the Menu-bar (of Safari) select Develop -> iPhone Simulator -> [your webview page].

  The beauty is it works for UIWebView,WKWebView too..

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12552686/730807)

Comment: You can attach the Safari web inspector to an embedded WKWebView in an iOS application running on an attached physical device. You first have to open the settings on the iOS device, navigate to Safari, Advanced, and switch on Web Inspector.

Answer (score 5):

With the device (or the simulator) connected and running your app, launch Safari on your Mac and go to the Develop menu (you'll have to enable it in Safari settings). The device and web view will show up in the menu:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Finally a real answer. And it has no upvotes, how?

Answer (score 1):

The web inspector is not available on iOS.