# UIWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString debugging

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I'm trying to achieve a relatively simple result - focus on a textBox when page is loaded. I use this code:

```
[_webView setKeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction:NO];

NSString *javaString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('keyboard').focus()"];
NSString *result = [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaString];
```

It's called by a button click in my app. This code worked on the test page, but doesn't work on the actual site. The worst part is that I don't know any way to debug this.

Nothing happens and result is always empty string. How do I check if there's an error in JS code? Or it can't find the object? Or it can't focus on it?

**UPDATE**

As rightly noted by @subzero, I forgot the actual focus() method in the question. It's correct now.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add the `focus` action

```
document.getElementById('keyboard').focus();"
```

will do the trick

About checking JS errors. There are 2 ways to do it.

1. The easy one:
   Add this (I'm ussing jQuery). It will show the errors at the bottom of the page

   $( document ).ready(function() {

   ```
   window.onerror = function(err) {
       log('window.onerror: ' + err)
   }
   var uniqueId = 1
   function log (message, data) {
           var log = document.getElementById('log')
           var el = document.createElement('div')
           el.className = 'logLine'
           el.innerHTML = uniqueId++ + '. ' + message + ':<br/>' + JSON.stringify(data)
           if (log.children.length) { log.insertBefore(el, log.children[0]) }
           else { log.appendChild(el) }
   }
   ```

in your html:

```
<div id='log'></div>
```

2. See this [What are some methods to debug Javascript inside of a UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767902/what-are-some-methods-to-debug-javascript-inside-of-a-uiwebview)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the debugging tips. And of course I forgot the focus() action in the question, it's there in the actual code.