# Debug HTML/JS in UIWebView on Windows

Tags: javascript, windows, debugging, uiwebview

I have a HTML page with JS code which works perfectly on Android and Desktop browsers, but fails on iOS. Is there any way to debug this page in iOS UIWebView on Windows with Chrome (like remote devices with Android)?

Comment: also official [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are some methods to debug Javascript inside of a UIWebView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767902/what-are-some-methods-to-debug-javascript-inside-of-a-uiwebview)

Comment: @oboshto I saw this topic. But they're talking about debugging it from osX, while I need to debug it from Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I made some search about this, and i think it may work if you use [Weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/), give it a try.