# Unable to inspect web view in ios

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, ipad, uiwebview

I am a Front end developer. my issue is some of my angular modules are loaded in web view which is did by ios developer.am having some ui issue and functionality problem but in my web pages it works fine. I don't know how to inspect myweb view even i have followed some video's in youtube but it didn't help.

I wants to see request and response in web view.My project is developing in angularjs.is it possible to inspect webview?

Comment: i assume that you have not done a complete research at SO before posting this question !! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767902/what-are-some-methods-to-debug-javascript-inside-of-a-uiwebview

Answer (score 0):

step 1: First Connect your device.
step 2: open safari.
step 3: then select developer option from your safari tab bar.
step 4: select your mobile name which is connected.
step 5: it will show your current page for example: index.html.
step 6: then a click on network and you will find your request/response.